# Syntax highlighting (contains, contained) of only the first match

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I think it is possible but can not figure how one can highlight only the first match of contained syntax?

```
syn clear
syntax cluster TitleParts contains=TitleNum,TitleType,TitleRest
syntax match MyTitle /\v^\s+\d+\)\s+.*$/ contains=@TitleParts
syntax match TitleNum /\v\s+\d+\)\s*/ contained nextgroup=TitleType
syntax match TitleType /\v(this|that)/ contained
syntax match TitleRest /\v\(.+\)/ contained
hi link MyTitle Title
hi link TitleNum Statement
hi link TitleType Type
hi link TitleRest Comment

  1) this Hello World this (Bla bla bla 1 2 3 4 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer while experimenting... not sure if this is the best one :)

```
syn clear
syntax cluster TitleParts contains=TitleFront,TitleTail
syntax match TitleFront /\v^\s+\d+\)\s((this|that)\s)?/ contains=TitleNum,TitleType containedin=@TitleParts
syntax match MyTitle /\v^\s+\d+\)\s+.*$/ contains=@TitleParts
syntax match TitleNum /\v\s+\d+\)\s*/ contained containedin=TitleFront
syntax match TitleType /\v(this|that)/ contained containedin=TitleFront
syntax match TitleTail /\v\(\d+\)\s\(.{-}\)$/ contained containedin=MyTitle
hi link MyTitle Title
hi link TitleNum Statement
hi link TitleType Type
hi link TitleTail Comment

  123) this Hello World this (1) (Bla bla bla 1 2 3 4 5)

  1) that Hello World this (22) (Bla bla bla 1 2 3 4 5)
```

[image]